# Using pointers for boolkeys

Tags: xkeyval

I'm trying to do something like:

```
\usepackage{xkeyval}
...
\makeatletter
\define@boolkey{fam}{keya}[true]{}
\define@boolkey{fam}{keyb}[true]{}
\makeatother

\setkeys{fam}{\savevalue{keya}=false,
              keyb=\usevalue{keya}
}.
```

The problem is that one apparently cannot say `keyb=\usevalue{keya}`, because an error message is displayed, saying:

> Package xkeyval Error: value `\@empty false' is not allowed.

Is there a way to get the code working though?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to update your distribution, your example run without problems on my system `texlive 2016`